# Print the results from re.findall on a seperate line in Python3

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I want to print findall results on a new line for every match

### Python Code

```
import urllib.request
import re

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://basketball.realgm.com/")

htmltext = htmlfile.read().decode('iso-8859-1')
title = re.findall('">(.+?)</a></h3>', htmltext)

print (title)
```

#### Results

```
['LeBron James Exercises Early Termination Option With Heat', 'LeBron James Exercises Early Termination Option With Heat', 'Heat, Hawks Could Join Pursuit Of Carmelo Anthony', 'Tyler Dorsey Decommits From Arizona', 'Antoine Mason Transfers To Auburn', 'Dario Saric Signs Three-Year Deal With Anadolu Efes', 'Batum To Participate In FIBA World Cup For France', 'Moustapha Diagne Commits To Syracuse']
```

## Want Results like this:

```
LeBron James Exercises Early Termination Option With Heat
Heat, Hawks Could Join Pursuit Of Carmelo Anthony
Tyler Dorsey Decommits From Arizona
```

Tried:

```
print (title \n)
```

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: @m.wasowski I just added what I tried. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

`print("\n".join(title))`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop.

```
for t in title:
    print(t)
```

Comment: @timgeb how to you know that?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda urllib.request

Comment: Yikes, python 3, whaddidido?